# Sorting arraylist in correct order in Objective C

Tags: ios, arrays, sorting

I have a list of array keys that i am getting from a dictionary by using below code :

```
    NSArray*keys=[dictionary allKeys];
```

Value of keys are coming like this :

```
Fact tags - 1                                     ,
Fact tags - 14                                    ,
Brochure                                          ,
Balloon                                           ,
Fact tags - 10                                    ,
Fact tags - 2                                     ,
Fact tags - 12                                    ,
Fact tags - 3                                     ,
Booklet                                           , 
Fact tags - 15                                    ,
Fact tags - 5                                     ,
Fact tags - 13                                    ,
Fact tags - 4                                     ,
Fact tags - 11                                    ,
Fact tags - 6                                     ,
Fact tags - 9                                     ,
Fact tags - 8                                     ,
Fact tags - 7                                     ,
```

So, for array list sorting. i am using below code:

```
keys = [keys sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];
```

Now, my keys output is :

```
Balloon                                           ,
Booklet                                           ,
Brochure                                          ,
Fact tags - 1                                     ,
Fact tags - 10                                    ,
Fact tags - 11                                    ,
Fact tags - 12                                    ,
Fact tags - 13                                    ,
Fact tags - 14                                    ,
Fact tags - 15                                    ,
Fact tags - 2                                     ,
Fact tags - 3                                     ,
Fact tags - 4                                     ,
Fact tags - 5                                     ,
Fact tags - 6                                     ,
Fact tags - 7                                     ,
Fact tags - 8                                     ,
Fact tags - 9                                     ,
```

Here it is sorting an array alphabetically, But i want my array list output like below list:

```
Balloon                                          ,
Booklet                                          ,
Brochure                                         ,
Fact tags - 1                                    ,
Fact tags - 2                                    ,
Fact tags - 3                                    ,
Fact tags - 4                                    ,
Fact tags - 5                                    ,
Fact tags - 6                                    ,
Fact tags - 7                                    ,
Fact tags - 8                                    ,
Fact tags - 9                                    ,
Fact tags - 10                                   ,
Fact tags - 11                                   ,
Fact tags - 12                                   ,
Fact tags - 13                                   ,
Fact tags - 14                                   ,
Fact tags - 15                                   ,
```

Can you please tell me that what changes i need to do in my code for such type of sorting ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you try with **sortedArrayUsingComparator**,

try Like,

```
keys = [keys sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2) {
        return [(NSString *)obj1 compare:(NSString *)obj2 options:NSNumericSearch];
    }];
```

Comment: mcaYeah sure..but i can accept this answer after 8 minutes only. now 5 min is remaining accrdng to stackoverflow.

Comment: @AnandGautam: I got thought on this, **Tester aur Developer ki sirf Dushmani ho sakti he** - Dhoom Style. ha ha ha.

Answer (score 2):

Best way to do...

```
 keys = [keys sortedArrayUsingComparator:^(NSString* first, NSString* second){

         return [first compare:second options:NSNumericSearch | NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
            }
        ];
```

You can also use custom objects instead of `NSString`